# How to edit all the different context menu entries of the Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

I'd like to write a script to simplify editing the context menus of the Windows Explorer. 
But there seem to be A LOT of different ways to implement context menu entries and non of the sites that I found covered them all.

Some entries are file specific, some are folder specific, some are file extension specific, some are simple registry entries, some are based on dll or exe files and then there are speperators, submenus, checkbox/radiobutton implementations, icons and some entries are showing in bold.

I just want to know where I find all these entries and how I could edit or remove them.
I'm also wondering if there isn't a WinAPI function or COM object that would make it easier to manipulate the context menus. This would also likely be a way more future proof solution then registry entries.

Comment: [Add, Remove, Edit Context Menu items in Windows 7 | 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors)

Comment: @DavidPostill But this again doesn't cover all the things I mentioned. For example the "Refresh" entry and menu seperators. The author just says that the "Refresh" entry cannot be removed, in the comments, which is not true as I did it in the past, I can't remember how, though.

Comment: You can remove Refresh. But don't expect Explorer to always work.

Comment: Well, I've never had any problems with it. If something doesn't work anymore you can always restore your file.. Btw, the "Reload" entry was stored as resource script in %windir%\System32\en-US\shell32.dll.mui (Menu\215\1033)